# NGINX configuration regex in location

Tags: nginx

Coming from 15+ years of using Apache's web server, I wanted to give the new kid a chance. ;) 
I have been trying to tweak my NGINX configuration files for brevity.

The site generally rewrites all the traffic to a specific `index.php`, but I have two directories `privacy` and `eula` which contain individual `index.php`s, so for those two directories I want it to just call the files in the directories.

For example:

```
location ~ /(privacy|eula) {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

causes my browser to download the pages content as a .dms file.

If I split the location into two like so:

```
location /privacy {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /eula {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

It works as intended.

I searched and also found the suggestion to do it this way, but that had the same effect `location ~ ^/(privacy|eula)`.
Do I just have to live with the fact that NGINX is very verbose, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *regular expression* `location` blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found.

In your case, you have placed `location ~ /(privacy|eula)` above the `location ~ \.php$` block, so that a URI like `/eula/index.php` will not be processed by the correct location and will be downloaded instead.

Place the `location ~ /(privacy|eula)` block **after** the `location ~ \.php$` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.